# Responsive iFrame Content for mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

My iframe is already responsive both on mobile and website, but my problems is the content itself which always overflow (overflow X and Y) from the width and height of my iFrame.

Here is the real situation - mobile view (i'm using google chrome to mimic display at Galaxy Note 3, Pixel, Nexus 7 etc)

[image: Problem]

And the way it should look - web view
[image]

As you can see, the content is overflow. I'm Android Engineer so I'm not expert in Web Front-End.

Here is what I have done. I have 2 possible solutions to make my iFrame responsive.

First one, wrapping to this style

```
<style>
    .responsive-video {
        position: relative;
        padding-bottom: 56.25%;
        padding-top: 60px; overflow: hidden;
    }

    .responsive-video iframe,
    .responsive-video object,
    .responsive-video embed {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    iframe {
        width:400px;
        height:600px;
        overflow-x:hidden;
        overflow-y:hidden;
    }
</style>

<div class="responsive-video">
    <iframe src="http://localhost/html/media/html_games/test_games"></iframe>
</div>
```

Second one, using bootstrap

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="http://localhost/html/media/html_games/test_games"></iframe>
</div>
```

Both solutions make the iFrame responsive to mobile and web, but not with the content. Please help how to make the content responsive so on the mobile user no need to scroll Y as seen in the first screenshot problem appears.

```css
.resp-container {
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
            padding-top: 56.25%;
        }

.resp-iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="resp-container">
        <iframe class="resp-iframe" src="https://dev-wma-051-ccwuh3zg.qreatiq.net/media/html_games/fbibekasi_games1513/" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
```

above is my snippet code, the code above works fine on the browser but will overflow its content when it view from mobile. Eg. galaxy note3, Pixel 2 etc.

Here is look if the snippet running on the mobile view, i need to scroll to view all the content. I wanted to content fit to the iFrame.
[image: problem at mobile view]

Comment: can u provide a snippet or live demo?

Comment: Snippet added, please run it using mobile view and you will see the content is overflow than the iframe itself, does it problem on the content which not responsive?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

i've inspected the code the problem is in the  tag of the iframe you can add `overflow:hidden` to it or u can do something about the zoom.